# How can I unit test a computed (get only) property in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, computed-properties

I wrote the following class extension on NSURL:

```
extension NSURL
{
    var linkComponents: LinkComponents
    {
        var pathComponents = self.pathComponents ?? []

        if let first = pathComponents.first where first == "/"
        {
            pathComponents.removeFirst()
        }

        return LinkComponents(components: pathComponents)
    }

    var linkPath: String
    {
        return self.path ?? ""
    }
}
```

It contains a computed (get-only) property:

```
var linkComponents: LinkComponents
```

When I attempt to test this computed property in my unit test target, the compiler throws and error saying `Ambiguous use of 'linkComponents'` and suggests a few "candidates".

This seems like an access control issue. My import statement in my test file has the `@testable` annotation. All of my other tests (for non-computed properties) compile a-ok without me having to specify any access control beyond the default `internal`. And if I convert this particular computed property into a function, the test target compiles a-ok.

Is it possible to unit test computed properties in Swift? If so, how? It goes without saying that (1) I don't want to convert this computed property to a function and (2) I don't want to add `public` to everything.

**Edit 1**

The "candidates" the compiler suggests is really only a single "candidate" and it's my computed property. I.e. the compiler correctly identifies the computed property but it won't officially recognize it as the one and only valid candidate.

**Edit 2**

Actually, converting it to a function doesn't work either. Given that I am testing functions from within an extension on a class that I wrote. Perhaps this has something to do with testing functions in extensions on Foundation classes (like NSURL in this case).

**Edit 3**

After further investigation is looks like this is due to the return type (`LinkComponents`) of the `linkComponents` computed property. The compiler doesn't like this. If I change the return type to `String` it's a-ok. And if I referent objects of type `LinkComponents` either in the test case itself or in the body of the computed property it's also a-ok. It's only when the computed property's type is `LinkComponents` that the compiler complains. Here is `LinkComponents`:

```
enum LinkComponents
{
    case None
    case Any(String, String?, String?, String?, String?)

    init(components: [String])
    {
        switch components.count
        {
        case 0:
            self = .None

        case 1:
            self = .Any(components[0], nil, nil, nil, nil)

        case 2:
            self = .Any(components[0], components[1], nil, nil, nil)

        case 3:
            self = .Any(components[0], components[1], components[2], nil, nil)

        case 4:
            self = .Any(components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3], nil)

        case 5:
            self = .Any(components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3], components[4])

        default:
            self = .Any(components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3], components[4])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  What are the "candidates" that compiler suggests?  Did you try cleaning up product / throwing away derived data?

Comment: See edits to question

Comment: Unfortunately cleaning and clearing derived data doesn't help

Comment: What version of XCode do you have?  Similar test on my version works fine.  I run XCode 7.3.1 (7D1014).

Comment: I've tried Xcode 7.3 and 7.3.1. I also just updated my question to include more info.